# Is there a more elegant way to remove a element from an array?

Tags: javascript

The way I am removing elements from my array right now is this

```
var indexToRemove = newSections.indexOf(newSections.find((section) => section.id === parseInt(sectionId)));
newSections.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
```

However, I want to be able to remove my elements as such.

```
array.remove(element)
```

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Not really. You can use lodash which will make your code more concise.

Comment: Is it possible to extend the array class? @EricGuan

Comment: @TimmyZubkisSearcy Extending built-in objects is generally not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an API to do such a thing in place, but you can do something similar with `Array.filter`.

```
let words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "happy"];

words = words.filter(word => word != "spray");
```

In the example above, `words` will not contain the word `spray`.

Comment: ie, `newSections = newSections.filter(section => section.id !== parseInt(sectionId))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the deletion in place, you can do a little better with `reduce`:

```
var indexToRemove = newSections.reduce(
    (acc,section,index) =>
        (acc === null && section.id === parseInt(sectionId) ? index : acc),
    null);
if (indexToRemove !== null)
    newSections.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
```

So you array is parsed only once.

Otherwise I would prefer the answer with `find`

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the following**

```
sections = [
    {id: 1, name: 'section 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'section 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'section 3'}
]
```

**Define simple function**

```
function removeSection(sections, sectionIdToRemove) {
  return sections.filter(s=>s.id != parseInt(sectionIdToRemove)
}
```

**Use it**

```
removeSection(sections, 1) // removes the second section
```

it is not recommended to add such a `.remove` method to the global `Array` Object.